# Trying to create a CSV file from a text file in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, csv

I have a text file that contains passwords and their respective hashes that is formatted as such:

```
'plaintext password'
'SHA256 hash'
'SHA3-512 hash'
```

This format continues for several more passwords. Each password and hash has its own line within the file. Each of the hashes below the 'plaintext password' are its respective hashes. I want to create a CSV file that will end up looking like this:

```
'plaintext password','SHA256 hash','SHA3-512 hash'
```

Essentially, I want to combine those three fields into one line for each password, delimited by commas for each field. I have tried searching for similar situations to mine but with no avail. I have tried awk as well as tr -s, but I haven't been able to get exactly what I want. I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 10):

You can try

```
paste -d, - - - < file.txt > file.csv
```

The `paste` command generally merges lines of *files* side-by-side (with an optional delimiter supplied by `-d`). In this case we are telling it to read the standard input stream 3 times `- - -` instead.

Comment: That did the trick! Would you mind explaining what the hyphenations do? I understand the paste command as well as the -d flag, but why the extra three hyphens?

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian I have added a brief explanation

Comment: @steeldriver just out of curiosity, is it possible to generates separate columns for each word per line, e.g: `(Line #1) This is line number one. (Line #2) This line have fewer words. (Line #3) This line number three have more words in it than other lines.` Thanks.

Comment: @Jags that sounds like a separate (different) question - although the formating limitations of the comment box make it hard to know exactly what you're asking

Comment: @steeldriver Okay, I've just asked a separate question. Thanks. `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214160/create-a-csv-file-from-txt-file`